# How to search item in Ilist and hence display the output?

Tags: c#

How can i search the client name from the Ilist by using ClientID. i am unable to figure it out.I have created a simple class named clientdetails and made a connection with a oracle database .Now i simply want to search the list by using ClientID and hence display the result.

Thanks AK.

```
class ClientDetails
{
    public string ClientID;
    public string ClientName;
    public string CreatedBy;
    public string UpdatedBy;

    public ClientDetails(string ClientID, string ClientName, string CreatedBy, string UpdatedBy)
    {
        this.ClientID = ClientID;
        this.ClientName = ClientName;
        this.CreatedBy = CreatedBy;
        this.UpdatedBy = UpdatedBy;
    }
}
class ConnectionSample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

        //using connection string to connect to oracle database
        IList<ClientDetails> myfield = new List<ClientDetails>();
        try
        {

            con.ConnectionString = "xxxxxconnection stringxxxxx";
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            string abc = "SELECT * FROM CLI_CLIENT_900";
            command.CommandText = abc;
            OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                myfield.Add(new ClientDetails(reader["CLIENT_ID"].ToString(), reader["CLIENT_NAME"].ToString(), reader["CREATED_BY"].ToString(), reader["UPDATED_BY"].ToString()));

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex, "Error");
        }
        //close and dispose oracleconnection object

        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();

        foreach (ClientDetails c1 in myfield.OrderByDescending(s => s.ClientID))
        {

            Console.Write("\n" + c1.ClientID);
            Console.Write("\t"+c1.ClientName);
            Console.Write("\t\t"+c1.UpdatedBy);
        }
    }
    static void Display(IList<string> myfield)
    {
        foreach (string value in myfield)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t"+value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you not perform the filtering in the *database*? And what's your actual *question*?

Comment: i want to perform the search operation on the list using clientid.

Comment: @AbeMiessler *hence* is fine here, if the OP means "how to search for an item and _thereby_ display it"

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `List` of items you can select specific items in the following way:

```
myfield.Where( t => t.ClientId == 1234);
```

This will return a collection of `ClientDetails` objects where the `ClientId` member is equal to 1234.

That said, this is probably filtering that you would be better off doing in the database unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `First/FirstOrDefault`:

```
ClientDetails client = myfield.FirstOrDefault(c => c.clientID == givenID);
if(client != null)
   Console.Write(client.ClientName);
else
   Console.Write("clientID not found");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the list in code you can use a simple LINQ query to get the desired results.

```
 var results = myList.Where(x => x.ClientId == clientIdImSearchingFor);

 foreach (Client c in results)
    // print client data
```

You could also just make this a loop with an if inside of it;

```
  foreach (Client c in ClientsList)
  {
       if (c.ClientId == ClientIdImSearchingFor)
           //print client data
  }
```

Also, if you want to filter with your SQL query (instead of after you serialize the results) you can use the same LINQ statement only MyList would instead be the Entity which represents the table.